# Asignar un valor diferente a un combo box del que se muestra en pantalla para subirlo a una base de datos? JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Buen día, agradecería mucho su ayuda con la siguiente cuestión:
verán, tengo esta función en donde mando algunos datos a una tabla dentro de una base de datos, la cosa es que en la parte donde dice nivel de usuario, necesito que en pantalla se muestren 26 niveles de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en cuando quiero mandar tales valores a la tabla, ya que esa columna de la tabla esta en INT, y necesito que dentro de la tabla se muestren los niveles en número, ejemplo: si escogiste "VISOR" en el combo box, en la tabla de la base de datos se tiene que mostrar "1" si escoges capturador se tendría que mostrar "2" y así sucesivamente, dejo parte del código que uso para subir los valores a la base de datos:

```
 public void registrarse() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, ParseException{

 NetClientPost net = new NetClientPost();
response = net.net(txt_pass.getText());
aObj = net.parsearJson();


   try{
         Connection con = Db.connect1();
       String SQL="INSERT INTO users(name,password,nivel_usuario) values(?,?,?)";
       PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pst.setString(1, txt_nombre.getText());
        //CONTRASEÑA ENCRIPTADA
        pst.setString(2, (String) aObj);
        pst.setString(3, (String) Nivelbox.getSelectedItem());
        pst.execute();
         Db db = new Db();
       db.cerrarConexion();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Los valores presentes en Nivelbox (Visor, Capturador, etc), ¿los ingresaste manualmente o son de una clase?

Comment: Los ingrese manualmente

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no tuve una respuesta encontré como solucionar mi problema y lo hice utilizando este simple método

```
     public String niveles(){
     if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Visor")){
     nivel = "1";
     } if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Capturador")){
     nivel = "2";
     } if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Administrador")){
     nivel = "3";
     } if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Admin. Agentes")){
     nivel = "4";
     } if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Coordinador CEDIS")){
     nivel = "5";
     } if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Auditoría")){
     nivel = "6";
     } if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Inventario")){
     nivel = "7";
     } if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Vigilancia")){
     nivel = "20";
      } if  
      (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Aduana")){
      nivel = "21";
      } if  
      (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Reporteador Reciclaje")){
     nivel = "22";
     } if  
     (Nivelbox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Recurso CEDIS")){
     nivel = "23";
     }
```

En lugar de mandar lo que esta dentro del nivelbox mando la variable nivel a la base de datos.